# Make images inside a slideToggle div to fade-in when entering viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of very large images on my site that FadeInUp when entering the viewport.
Each of these images works also as a toggle button to vertically slide open a div that contains other images. I would like also these images (inside the slidetoggle div) to FadeInUp when entering the viewport.

Once the div slides open, my code only works with the first image; all the others just enter the viewport with no effect, even if I gave the same class to all the images.

To animate my images, I am using the wow.js and the animate.css library (with the FadeInUp animation)
https://wowjs.uk

For the toggle panel this code: https://jsfiddle.net/bv0jyzq1/1/

Does anybody know where the problem might be?
The effect is applied to all the images only if I remove the

```
#show-images {display: none;}
```

which is obviously not what I want to do

Thanks

Edit: this is also my html code

```
<div id="project-images">
            <!-- Main IMG to Click -->
            <div id="toggle" class="wow fadeInUp">
                <img src="..."/>
            </div>

            <!-- Slides Open -->
            <div id="show-images">
                <div>
                    <img class="wow fadeInUp" src="..."/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="wow fadeInUp" src="..."/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img class="wow fadeInUp" src="..."/>
                </div>
            </div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: You can't animate `display` property in css -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: the "display:none;" is applied to the whole div that appears when toggled. I am looking to apply the sliding effect to the images inside it. The animation only works with the first image and not the others...